# Why do i have infinite while loop?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, infinite

I want to cut a list into sublists of a given length (let it be 2 for example). To solve this task i have 1st while loop for the indices in the list and 2nd while loop with the counter of 2. I do increment my counter every cycle of the 2nd while loop and it still gets infinite. Why?

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] 
i = 0 
chunk = 2 
list2 = [] 
while i < len(list1): 
    element = [] 
    counter = 0 
    while counter <= chunk: 
        element.append(list[i])
        counter += 1 
    list2.append(element) 
print(list2)
```

Comment: `i` is always zero, hence the infinite loop.

Comment: Is this your real code? Surely this code produces an error.

Comment: You never update `i` so `i < len(list1)` will always be true

Comment: You set `i` equal to 0 then never change the value of `i` ... thus `i` will always be less than your list's length

Comment: You might also want to check out: https://sopython.com/canon/14/splitting-a-list-into-even-chunks/

Comment: @quamrana: The code is perfectly valid, both syntactically and semantically, and it is type-safe. It just doesn't terminate. Why would it produce an error?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: because `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. (`list[i]` should be `list1[i]` I suppose.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Sorry, I assumed that `list[0]` would produce an error. I didn't realise that `<class 'list'>` responded to such calls.

Comment: @quamrana: All the collection types now respond to `__getitem__` to make it possible to have type annotations like `list[int]` without getting runtime errors.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: So the OP has more problems than an infinite loop then!

Answer (score 0):

`i` is set to `0` on line 2 and never changed. Therefore, `i < len(list1)` will always be `True`, unless `list1` is empty (which it isn't because it is initialized on line 1 and never changed).

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because in your first loop, the condition i < len (list1) will never not be true (i.e will always be true)
your second loop will end as counter is incremented, so eventually counter <= chunk will be true
the first loop, i is never incremented, so it remains constant (so 0 ) and thus will never exit the while loop

open for correction as I dont have much experience with python

Comment: Thank You! Yes, thats the case

Answer (score 0):

Because in your loop variable i is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

You're never updating your value for `i` thus it is always 0. Just put `i += 1` at the end of your while loop like this:

```py
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] 
i = 0 
chunk = 2 
list2 = [] 
while i < len(list1): 
    element = [] 
    counter = 0 
    while counter <= chunk: 
        element.append(list[i])
        counter += 1 
    list2.append(element) 
    i += 1
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[[list[0], list[0], list[0]], [list[1], list[1], list[1]], [list[2], list[2], list[2]], [list[3], list[3], list[3]], [list[4], list[4], list[4]], [list[5], list[5], list[5]], [list[6], list[6], list[6]]]
```